# jQuery: inserting text into container div on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I'm using a simple jQuery image slider (Owl Carousel) to show a list of speakers at a convention with photos, and I'm trying to find a way to overlay text associated with each speaker onto a div placed above the slider. I have a mockup page [**here**](http://nickpish.com/_dev/mc-slider-test2/). As you can see on the mockup, I have two primary divs-- i.e. `div#sit` and `div#carousel-sit`; within the former I have an container with the class `.sit-quote-container` into which I'd like the quote text/markup injected. I would like this overlay text to pull from the paragraph elements with the `.sit-quote` class that exist for each speaker.

In addition to the problem of displaying the appropriate text within the container div, I'm seeing that placing the `.sit-quote` paragraph within each slide is causing a gap to appear under the speaker name (the grey box underneath) and I have no idea why this is happening given that I've set `.sit-quote` to `display:none`. I'm wondering if perhaps I need to move the elements containing the quotations out of the slider markup altogether (?)

As for the actual hover function, this is what I have so far, with the help of another SO user; but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
$(".slide-sit").hover(function() {
    var clone = $(this).find(".sit-quote").clone();
    clone.appendTo(".sit-quote-container");
}, function(){
    $(".sit-quote-container").html(""); // this clears the content on mouseout
});
```

Ultimately, I'd like the quotes to fade in/out positioned within the main div. Thanks for any assistance, and please let me know if I need to provide further clarification as to the aim here.

Comment: You'd generally be better of with just showing and hiding, rather than appending and removing.

Comment: Ok, but the aim is to pull the contents from various divs marked with a specific class, i.e. `.sit-quote` and display them in a container above (.`sit-quote-container`) on hover; please see my mockup for further clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below script to pull the text from `.sit-quote` p tag  of the hovered item and display it in the `.sit-quote-container`

**UPDATE**

If needed wrap the quote in a para tag and to avoid complexity use a different class name, in this case `.sit-quote_inner`.

CSS : `.sit-quote_inner{ display:none; }`

JS

```
    $('.sit-carousel-container .owl-item').hover(function(){
       var quote = $(this).find('.sit-quote').text(); //Only text not the p tag
       quote = '<p class="sit-quote_inner">' + quote + '</p>';
      $('.sit-header .sit-quote-container').html(quote);
       $('.sit-quote_inner').fadeIn(); //Add this
    },function(){
      $('.sit-header .sit-quote-container').html('');
    });
```

Comment: thanks Karan-- I'm wondering how I might pull the whole block, i.e. with markup, not just the text, as I'd like  to style the elements therein-- ultimately with a semi-transparent white background behind the text and a way to cite the speaker name in italics

Comment: thanks again Karan-- one last question: is there an easy way to make to block fade in/out the way you have it implemented?

Comment: Great! Makes sense; I'll give it a whirl.

Answer (score 2):

you should first visible that quote
try this:

```
$(".slide-sit").hover(function() {
    var clone = $(this).find(".sit-quote").clone();
    clone.appendTo(".sit-quote-container").show(); // Here you should show the quote
}, function(){
    $(".sit-quote-container").html("");
});
```

if you want to fade in:

```
$(".slide-sit").hover(function() {
    var clone = $(this).find(".sit-quote").clone();
    clone.appendTo(".sit-quote-container").fadeIn(); //Here if you want to fade the quote
}, function(){
    $(".sit-quote-container").html("");
});
```

Comment: Thanks Hitesh! I just updated my mockup with your code and it's working as far as displaying the text. Two issues remain though: (1) I'd like to style the overlayed text with a semi-transparent white background as I mentioned in the comment above; and (2) I'm having the strange issue with the gap under the slider elements, evening though I'm setting the quote paragraphs to `display:none`; any idea why that might be happening? Thanks again.

Comment: @nickpish 1) The gap you're talking about is not visible in your demo. Please provide a demo which reproduces the issue. 2) SO being a Q&A site, it's a bad practice to come up with new requirements once the issue in question is solved. That's better suited for another question if you're unable to do it after **trying**. *"I'd like to style the elements therein-- ultimately with a semi-transparent white background behind the text and a way to cite the speaker name in italics"*- did you try anything to do so? please don't misunderstand SO as a free coding service...

Comment: Your point has been made; I'm not here to engage in petty nonsense. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The carousel seems to be dynamically injecting clones of the slides. In this case, you might want to delegate your event handler so that it works with the dynamically generated slides.

Also, if you want to fadeOut the text, you should remove it in the complete callback of `fafeOut` instead of simply emptying the `html` Try

```
$(document).on("mouseenter",".slide-sit",function() {
   var clone = $(this).find(".sit-quote").clone();
   clone.appendTo(".sit-quote-container").fadeIn("slow");
});

$(document).on("mouseleave",".slide-sit", function(){
   $(".sit-quote-container")
   .find(".sit-quote")
   .fadeOut("slow",function(){ // Fadeout and then remove the text
      $(this).remove();
  })
});
```

The gap (*grey background*) is the background of `.slide-sit`, which is visible due to the `margin-bottom: 15px;` applied on the paragraph containing name (*style rule `.item p` main.css line 67 it seems*), removing this will fix the issue.

**Update**
It'd be better if you keep a `.slide-sit` inside the `.sit-quote-container` so that you can fade it in/out properly using the below script.

```
$(document).on("mouseenter",".sit-carousel-container .slide-sit",function() {
    var content = $(this).find(".sit-quote").html();
   (".sit-quote-container .sit-quote").html(content).fadeIn("slow");
});

$(document).on("mouseleave",".sit-carousel-container .slide-sit", function(){
   $(".sit-quote-container").find(".sit-quote").fadeOut("slow")
});
```

Comment: Oh man, it was inheriting that from `.item p`, ugh; thank you for pointing that out. Your help is much appreciated btw.

Comment: One more question for you: I've accepted your answer and it's working well; the only issue I'm having if you refer to my updated mockup is that the quote block seems to bounce up and down when moving from hovering over one slide to the next; do you know what might be causing this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @nickpish that is because the new quote is appended before the previous one is fadeout. It'd be better of if you keep a `.slide-sit` inside `.sit-quote-container` before hand in html, just change it's content and fade it in/out as in the update for properly fading out the quote.

Comment: Hm ok, I just updated my mockup and I must be doing something wrong. I added an empty `.slide-sit` within the quote container; should it have the `.sit-quote` class? Pardon if I'm misunderstanding...

Comment: @nickpish just add the `.sit-quote` alone… since that is the only thing you need to hide and show...